# Cross compiling: a C program using Eclipse IDE on linux, how do I compile in a raspberry pi 4?

Tags: c, linux, eclipse, cross-compiling, raspberry-pi4

I want to make a "hello world" C program using Eclipse IDE on Linux. then I want to compile with my raspberry pi 4 making a cross compiling. I searched some websites but i can´t find anything.

this is what i made but I don´t know what else I need. I tried following this tutorial:

https://www.gurucoding.com/eclipse_as_ide_for_raspberry_pi/04_cross_compilation_setup/

1. I created a new C program in Eclipse IDE using cross GCC:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/VVGKY.jpg

2. I Set cross-compiler prefix as "arm-linux-gnueabihf-" and cross-compiler path as "C:\rpi-eclipse\rpi-cross-toolchain\arm-linux-gnueabihf".

https://i.stack.imgur.com/WK59S.jpg

3.When I create the project, gets those 2 errors:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/86AKZ.jpg

4.I made sure to follow this step:
Open "C/C++ Build" -> "Settings" on the left side, then in the "Tool Settings" tab, in the "Cross Settings" screen, make sure Path is "C:\rpi-eclipse\rpi-cross-toolchain\arm-linux-gnueabihf\bin;C:\rpi-eclipse\rpi-cross-toolchain\mingw-make". You may copy and paste it for your convenience (select with mouse, Ctrl+C, Ctrl+V). Click "OK" when done:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/v1ocS.jpg

5.When I build the Debug doesn´t go the errors.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Os8fN.jpg

CONCLUSION:
I am forgetting something? I need to install something else?

I have team-viewer and Discord so if anyone wants to help me I would appreciate a lot.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

ONE ERROR SOLVED: "arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc" not found in PATH

this error is gone installing this in via console:
apt-get install gcc-arm-linux-gnueabihf

SECOND ERROR SOLVED: "arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++" not found in PATH

this error is gone installing this in via console:
apt-get install g++-arm-linux-gnueabihf